# View passwords in Jenkins job configuration

Tags: jenkins

I am settings some passwords in a Jenkins job.

However, once the password has been set, I cannot find a way to check the value again

[image]

How can I view the value stored in the `Password` field above?

Using `Jenkins ver. 2.89.4`

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to view passwords in plain text. Consider using a password manager of some kind for each build job.

Comment: can't be...this would be such a stupid and counter-productive design choice...

Comment: Yeah, I've always been annoyed by this as well, but I'm fairly sure it's impossible. However, almost no web apps allow you to view passwords on the site itself, so I don't see why it's a bad design.

Comment: Gitlab does allow this

Comment: this shouldn't be allowed for security reasons. You will need to store them somewhere else if they must be retrievable later.

Comment: I am admin, I have access to the job configuration, I have a job with 5-10 passwords, I need to now if something went wrong when entering the several passwords without losing 5 hours on something so trivial; this is not security, this is insanely poor design; and I say again there is a bunch of tools that allow you to do this